# How to send data from child component to parent component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Parent Componet:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import AllNeedStates from 'components/AllNeedStates/AllNeedStates.jsx'

    class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        needstate: 
        }
    }


    getNeedstate = (need) => {
        this.setState({
            needstate:need
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AllNeedStates onNeedStateChange={this.getNeedstate} />
                {
                    this.state.needstate ?
                    (
                        <p>null</p>
                    ):
                    (
                        <p>{ this.state.needstate }</p>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

    }

    export default Home;
```

child components:

```
import React.Component from 'react'

class Child extends Components {

    myFunc = () => {
        this.props.onNeedStateChange('data');
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.myFunc}>submit</button> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here i am trying to send some data from react child component to my parent component.
But i am getting below error.

```
TypeError: this.props.onNeedStateChange is not a function
```

Please have a look.

I need to change the state of parent when i click button on child component.

Comment: Why `class Child extends Components`? You should extend `Component`. You need some value for `needstate` in constructor or you have a syntax error. Have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/oqm56m80ky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also add the `constructor` in your child component, else it will not inherit the `props` from parent.

```
class Child extends Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props)
    }

    myFunc = () => {
        this.props.onNeedStateChange('data');
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.myFunc}>submit</button> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor is default in every Statefull component.So, `it will always inherit the props from parent.'

Comment: Now error is gone but i am not getting data in parent component

Answer (score 1):

(1) Initialize state by a default value,
(2)Check for empty/null while displaying in render()

```
//Parent Component 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AllNeedStates from "./Child";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      needstate: ""
    };
  }

  getNeedstate = need => {
    console.log(need);
    this.setState({
      needstate: need
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AllNeedStates onNeedStateChange={this.getNeedstate} />
        {this.state.needstate === null ? (
          <p>null</p>
        ) : (
          <p>{this.state.needstate}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan it would be nice if you upvote this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.